# send anonymous request to our web application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

[Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) is to make it very easy to add " Azure AD auth" to our App Service apps. But after we configured, we found that it asks users to  do AD auth once user access the home page (such as https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/). It is not what we want. We would like to add some URLS to my site that does not require Authentication

Comment: I swear I saw similar question a little while ago that was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, we can use URL Authorization Rules to add some URLs to your site that does not require Authentication. For more details, please refer to https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/11/17/URL-Authorization-Rules.html.

For example:

```
URL Authorization Rules
 7 minute read
Chris Gillum (MSFT) 11/17/2016 3:40:36 PM
One of the goals of Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization is to make it very easy to add "auth" to your App Service apps (which is why we often refer to it as Easy Auth). Most of our investments so far have been focused on creating a streamlined authentication setup experience. However, up until now authorization was something developers had to implement mostly on their own. Typically authorization rules involve restricting access to certain resources within your app. Ideally, such authorization rules can be just as simple to set up without writing a bunch of custom code. To that end, we're happy to announce the initial preview of URL Authorization Rules in App Service.
Configuration
In the initial preview, URL Authorization Rules are defined in an authorization.json file (if you prefer, we also support the YAML syntax inside an authorization.yaml file).  The feature is enabled automatically when you configure Easy Auth in the management portal and place either an authorization.json file or an authorization.yaml file in the D:\home\site\wwwroot directory of your App Service app. This means you can include the file in your app's source and easily deploy it via Git, Web Deploy, FTP, or any of the continuous deployment mechanisms supported by App Service. Here is the basic schema of the configuration file in the JSON syntax:
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "http_methods": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", ... ],
      "path_prefix": "/some/url/prefix",
      "policies": {
        "unauthenticated_action": "AllowAnonymous|RedirectToLoginPage|RejectWith401|RejectWith404"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the App Service Authentication to allow anonymous requests, as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#allow-only-authenticated-requests.

> Restricting access in this way applies to all calls to your app, which may not be desirable for apps wanting a publicly available home page, as in many single-page applications.

To trigger sign-in when desired,
add links or redirects to your app as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#use-multiple-sign-in-providers.

```
<a href="/.auth/login/aad">Log in with Azure AD</a>
<a href="/.auth/login/microsoftaccount">Log in with Microsoft Account</a>
<a href="/.auth/login/facebook">Log in with Facebook</a>
<a href="/.auth/login/google">Log in with Google</a>
<a href="/.auth/login/twitter">Log in with Twitter</a>
```

You will also need to add authorization checks in your back-end to the places where the user should be authenticated.